# UIImageView Spiral Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation, sprite

I need to animate an image view to go in a spiral path like how a roulette ball falls into a slot (no physics). See the picture below.

The image view with the ball image needs to start off at the top where the spiral starts and has to follow the white path and stop at the end of the spiral.

[image]

I've tried using anchor points, etc., but the desired result isn't happening. This just has the ball spinning around and around, but never dropping and going into the spiral.

```
CGPoint rotationPoint = anchorPointImageView.center;// The point we are rotating around

CGPoint anchorPoint =  CGPointMake((rotationPoint.x-201)/12.5, (rotationPoint.y-137)/12.5);

ballImageView.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
ballImageView.layer.position = rotationPoint;

CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotate.toValue = @(-M_PI*2); // The angle we are rotating to
rotate.duration = 2.32;
rotate.repeatCount = 3; // reset to 3

rotate.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
rotate.removedOnCompletion = NO;

[ballImageView.layer addAnimation:rotate forKey:@"myRotationAnimation"];
```

Comment: you need to move the ball center as well along with the rotation!

Answer (score 2):

That shape is a simple spiral. You could create it as a series of line segments using a little trig.

Feed in angles that start at zero and go to some multiple of 2 pi by small fractional steps

```
double angle = 0;
double spacing = 30
double end_angle = 20 * M_PI; //Do 10 360 degree arcs (2pi * 5)
double step = M_PI / 64; //128 steps per full circle, so lines are short.
double x,y;
do
{
  y = sin(angle) + angle * spacing;
  x = cos(angle) + angle * spacing;
  angle += step;
}
while angle < end_angle;
```

That code would generate a series of x/y points that would describe a spiral. You'd then use those points to build a UIBezierPath using `moveToPoint` and `lineToPoint` method calls. I leave fleshing it out to you. You'd change the spacing value depending on how much space you want between the passes around the arc, and the step value depending on how smooth you want the curve to look. Smaller step values will make for a smoother curve, but draw more slowly and take more memory. Larger step values will make it look more like a series of lines, but draw faster.

Once you've created your arc path you'd use it to create a key frame animation as described in Matt's answer.

### EDIT:

Remember that with a roulette wheel, the ball travels in a circle around the outside of the wheel for a while until it's speed drops enough that centripetal force doesn't hold it any more, and THEN it transitions to a spiral. You probably want 2 stages to your animation: First have it follow a circle at a slowly decreasing speed, and then switch to a spiral key frame animation.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is describe the spiral as a CGPath and then use [keyframe animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAKeyframeAnimation/path) to animate along the path. Of course you won't get a perfect spiral path — you'll have to construct it as a sequence of arcs approximating the spiral — but since the path is not *drawn* but merely followed by the rather large ball, this won't matter.

Comment: Using a series of arcs will not create a very believable spiral. That would create fixed radius arcs that jump to a different radius between them. Creating a path that's a true spiral is actually pretty easy. See my answer.

Comment: @DuncanC Cool! So I should have said a sequence of lines.